# SRSS Conditional formatting colour with value ranges?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a sql reporting services report that displays sales from all of our stores etc it includes a column which displays a % to budget value. What I want to do is if the value is `>= .35` then make it the background of the cell `Green`, if the value is `< .35 and > .30` then `Yellow` if the value is `< .30 then Red`.

It's really doing my head in I just can't seem to get it to work with all 3 ranges.

I can put in the background color properties of the cell the expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!ID__to_Budget.Value >= 0.35, "Green", "Red")
```

And that works, but of course I don't have any Yellow range, anything under .35 becomes red.

I have been trying to do a nested expression on the background color like this:

```
=iif( (Fields!ID__to_Budget.Value >= 0.35), "Green",
      ( iif(Fields!ID__to_Budget.Value <0.35 and > 0.30, "Yellow",
         iif(Fields!ID__to_Budget.Value < 0.30 "Red", "White") ) ) )
```

but it complains about a syntax error on the "and >0.30" part.

Many thanks
Lance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing a comma. But, nested Iifs are a pain, so to do the simple function route, I would use the `Switch` function for this, instead, so you don't have to nest anything--it will be easier to get the syntax right.

```
=Switch(
   Fields!ID__to_Budget.Value < 0.30, "Red",
   Fields!ID__to_Budget.Value < 0.35, "Yellow",
   Fields!ID__to_Budget.Value >= 0.35, "Green"
)
```

See [Reporting Services Expression Examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) for more on this function.

But it seems to me that encoding the "severity" of the values is something better done in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.BudgetSeverity (
   FromValue decimal(20, 10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   ToValue decimal(20,10) NOT NULL,
   SeverityLevel tinyint NOT NULL
);
INSERT dbo.BudgetSeverity
VALUES
   (-9999999999, 0.3, 1),
   (0, 0.35, 2),
   (0.35, 9999999999, 3)
;
```

Then in your data set, join to this table.

```
SELECT
   ...,
   BS.SeverityLevel
FROM
   ...
   INNER JOIN dbo.BudgetSeverity BS
      ON B.ID__to_Budget >= BS.FromValue
      AND B.ID__to_Budget < BS.ToValue
```

Finally, in your report:

```
=Choose(Fields!SeverityLevel.Value, "Red", "Yellow", "Green")
```

This way you can change the severity levels without having to deploy a new report. If you don't like the idea of putting this in the database, you still have other options. In the Code section of the report you could write a simple function to return a color based on the value passed in. Then you can use a Case statement which will be much, much easier to manage, and you can reuse this function in different fields, making it easier to update all of them at once if something changes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a SeverityColour than a SeverityLevel in your BudgetSeverity table? Then you could just use the SeverityColour field as your colour expression. The advantage of this is if you want to add another level, say a Blue level above 0.45, you can just add it to the table and not have to edit any reports to change the =Choose() statement. All the SeverityLevel is doing is feeding the calculation of the colour within the report which seems like an unnecessary step.

Comment: @Chris I thought about that, and it's perfectly viable. I just decided that SeverityLevel is data and SeverityColor is presentation.  Your choice.

Comment: @ErikE True, I was coming more from the DRY principle. If they change their minds about the colours, say deciding they want Orange rather than Yellow, doing it in the database means one change whereas using an expression means changing every report. If it is one report you're okay either way, if it is 100 reports and you used an expression you're in for a boring day. Depending on needs, I'd probably use both, so I could select "WHERE SeverityLevel = 1" plus have the SeverityColour field for consistency across the reports without repeating the colour expression.

Comment: @ChrisLatta It is perfectly viable, though I would have a separate report schema to define presentation things like color. There are a host of things in a report that one *could* make data-driven: font, font color, size, padding, bold, italics, underline, and so on and so forth. If you want to change these across 100 reports you have a similar problem. So it all depends on where you think you want to spend your time and what things you think will be likely to change in the future. For me, it was certain that the exact numeric values of the ranges would be more likely to change than the colors.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `,` in the last `iff clause` for the `condition` and the color `Red`

```
=iif(Fields!ID__to_Budget.Value >= 0.35, "Green",
     iif(Fields!ID__to_Budget.Value <0.35 &
          Fields!ID__to_Budget.Value> 0.30,"Yellow", 
         iif(Fields!ID__to_Budget.Value < 0.30, "Red","White") ) )
    )
```